# How to pass a std::function from Objective-C++ to C++ method

Tags: c++, objective-c, c++11, lambda, objective-c++

I'm trying to create a `std::function` within an Objective-C++ method, and pass it to a C++ method.

However I'm getting a bad access exception. I've tried using an Objective-C block and a lambda:

Using a block:

```
std::function<void(void)> callback = ^{
    [self doSomething];
};

callback(); // <-- this works

self.myCppObject-> setButtonCallback(callback);
```

Using a lambda:

```
std::function<void()> callback = [self]() {
    [self doSomething];
};

callback(); // <-- this works

self.myCppObject->setButtonCallback(callback);
```

In my C++ class:

```
void MyCppClass::setButtonCallback (std::function<void()> callback)
{
    buttonCallback = std::move (callback); // <-- crash here
}
```

I've also tried storing `callback` in the Objective-C++ class as a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) std::function<void()> callback;
```

The exception is thrown here: (line 1717 from `<functional>`)

```
template<class _Rp, class ..._ArgTypes>
function<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)>&
function<_Rp(_ArgTypes...)>::operator=(function&& __f) _NOEXCEPT
{
    if (__f_ == (__base*)&__buf_) // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS here
        __f_->destroy();
    else if (__f_)
        __f_->destroy_deallocate();
    __f_ = 0;

    ...
```

Which comes from the callback assignment in the C++ method. I tried using both `std::move` and copy via `=`.

**UPDATE**

The issue turned out to be that myCppObject had not been initialised, as it was a subclass of a class which initialised it in its constructor, however I was calling the base `[super init]` instead of the `[super initWith...]` that I needed. Thanks to @Roman for the clue.

Comment: Where exactly is the exception thrown?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall info added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to run your code and I received the same error only if property `self.myCppObject` was not initialised before. Try to replace

```
self.myCppObject-> setButtonCallback(callback);
```

with

```
self.myCppObject = new MyCppClass();
self.myCppObject-> setButtonCallback(callback);
```

or check if your properly initialised property `self.myCppObject`.

Comment: Interesting, `myCppObject` should have been initialised before being passed to this class, maybe something to do with initialisation order. Will investigate tomorrow, thanks.